# Good printer with cheap ink

Tags: printer

I'm looking for a home printer that is capable of good quality prints. Here are my requirements:

- It should have scan/copy capabilities
- I should be able to connect via USB, Wi-Fi is a bonus
- Price range for the printer should be low: under CAD 150
- Ink shouldn't be ridiculously expensive: Maximum CAD 90 to get a full cartridge set (black and colour ink)
- It should be available in Canada.

Comment: Are you excluding laser printers? Technically, they use toner, not ink - your use of 'ink' makes it unclear. Thoughts?

Comment: What Undo said above. Color laser printers have come down *significantly* in price in recent years, and while the price per purchase of consumables tends to be higher, those consumables also (generally speaking) last *significantly* longer, which brings the cost per printed page down *a lot*. Because toner is already dry, you also don't have to use them regularly to keep the cartridges from drying out. I would recommend that you focus more on cost per printed page (note that this varies by color coverage) than the cost of a replacement set of print matter (ink or toner).

Answer (score 4):

I have the [Canon MX340 Series Printer](http://www.canon.ca/inetCA/en/arcproducts/method/gp/pid/1214).

[image: Image of printer]

I've been using ths printer for roughly 3-4 years and it's been consistently reliable. According to [this](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2362811,00.asp) review, it comes for only $99, which is incredibly cheap. Ink is also really cheap: [a two-cartridge pack](http://www.staples.ca/en/Canon-PG-210XL-CL-211XL-Black-Colour-Ink-Cartridges-High-Yield-Value-Pack/product_775543_2-CA_1_20001) comes for around $60.

- The printer is accessible over USB, as well as Wi-Fi
- It has Copy/Scan capabilities
- And if I have one in Canada, it's probably available in Canada

Here's a few extras:

- The UI on the printer is sleek, and easy to use. No fiddle of buttons that make you curse at a printer
- It also has fax capabilities
- The resolution for photo prints is really good, coming under 4800x600 dpi.

This is an excellent printer that has served me well, and is reliable - I've used this countless times, and have made hundreds of jobs through it. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Canons also are refillable, if you don't mind keeping a track of ink yourself. I think I bought ink for ~40 sgd... I don't remember how many years ago.

Comment: Do you find ink is wasted with the color combined into one cartridge?