# Cheap all-in-one wifi printer with cheap ink (deliverable soon in the UK)

Tags: printer, cheap

Similar to [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/762/good-printer-with-cheap-ink), but that is 5 years old and Canada based.

I am looking for a cheap all-in-one (print & scan/copy) printer, USB connection (I don't mind paying an extra fiver for WiFi, but can live without it).

I am thinking "total cost of ownership", so want something that won't break the bank when it comes to buying refill ink.

Must be deliverable, in the UK (owing to Corona virus lock-down), and soon (amazon seems to be de-prioritizing some ares, including tech, in favour of others, such as food).

I need to something printed, posted and received in the UK by the end of the month.

Comment: For total cost of ownership, you probably need to factor how often you print & your ink coverage - documents or photos etc. A laser will have a higher initial cost but will last longer. I have low output requirements but my last laser lasted 10 years before the ink [toner] ran out. An inkjet, of which I had many before that, would have dried out in a month or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cheapest that I could find - that is available for delivery during the epidemic - was 
an [Epson Expression Home XP-2105 Wireless Inkjet Printer](https://www.argos.co.uk/product/9172874) for £39.99, plus £3.95 delivery (same day).

I imagine that, as usual, it will come with half-cartridges. But, frankly, I am coming to see that buying a new printer is cheer than buying ink, so will probably continue to do so in future. If I buy a dedicated scanner, or just keep this printer to use its scanner features, then I can buy even cheaper printers in future, with no scanning capability.

[image]

Printer:

```
Compatible with PC and Mac.
A4 print speed - black text: 8ppm (pages per minute).
A4 print speed - colour text: 4ppm (pages per minute).
Up to 5760 x 1440dpi print resolution.
Up to 5760 x 1440dpi colour print resolution.
Fits paper up to A4.
50 sheet paper capacity.
Uses 4 ink cartridges.
Recommended ink: Starfish 603.
```

Scanner and copier:

```
1200 x 2400dpi optical resolution.
```

Connectivity:

```
Suitable for photo printing.
Wireless/WiFi enabled.
Email Print.
Mobile print enables printing direct from your smartphone or tablet through brand specific apps.
```

General information:

```
Photo editing software included.
Weight 4.82kg.
Includes Full set of Ink, Power Cable & Instructions Manual.
Ink cartridge included.
Size H19.3, W37, D45.5cm.
EAN: 8715946665443.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been happy with my Brother monochrome printer/scanner/copier after finding a good review at [BoingBoing.net](https://boingboing.net/2019/06/18/cheap-wireless-laser-printer-w.html) which wwas specific as to its low cost of operation, and mine only cost me $80 Stateside.  Here's [a link for shopping](https://www.google.com/search?q=Brother%20USB%20monochrome%20scanner%20printer&tbs=vw:l,mr:1,root_cat:539072,pdtr0:959658%7C3639070,pdtr1:960877%7C960878,pdtr2:960893%7C960896,cat:500106,pdtr3:960880%7C960881,init_ar:SgeyBAQIwPMg&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi41d6fp7boAhXPHDQIHV_iC-UQsysIjBIoAA&biw=1436&bih=648): I regret I can't search on UK local vendors only, but I have read of many UK users of these printers. Also, the Big River Trading Post in your friendly nation does have at least [one model listed](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B078GS3TSJ/ref=emc_b_5_t) when I searched there for "Brother MFC mono laser" and it did have USB connectivity.

Comment: I could not find one available for delivery

Comment: Sympathies. The Google Shopping link I provided has a list of vendors further down the left pane. You may find one of those UK vendors has it even if they didn't tell Google.